# Retrieving five random items from a list using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

How can I retrieve randomly selected five different items from a list using sed? My list is something like below. Each item begins with an asterisk at the beginning of a line.

```
* asterisk*
star
wildcard
* bee
hive
* car
tire
drive
* dove
white
peace
* eel
slippery
* fin
fish
* goat
* hinge
door
* ice
cold
* jam
bread
```

I want random five different items like these:

```
* hinge
door
* ice
cold
* jam
bread
* asterisk*
star
wildcard
* eel
slippery
```

How can I do that?

I'm using OSX and I couldn't use semicolons in sed and I had to use gshuf instead of shuf. I tried this:

```
sed -e '1b' -e 's/^*/\x0*/' mypath | gshuf -zn 5 | tr -d '\000'
```

but it seems it just added the literal "x0"s instead of null character and it gave me this:

```
* asterisk*
star
wildcard
x0* bee
hive
x0* car
tire
drive
x0* dove
white
peace
x0* eel
slippery
x0* fin
fish
x0* goat
x0* hinge
door
x0* ice
cold
x0* jam
bread
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: what do you mean by *random five different items* ?

Comment: I mean there shouldn't be a duplicate within the five randomly selected items.

Comment: it should have 5 items which starts with `*` ?

Comment: Yes, the asterisk in the middle of a line doesn't count as a separator, though. The first three line in the original list above count as one item for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `gnu sed/shuf`:

```
sed '1b;s/^*/\x0*/' infile | shuf -zn 5 | tr -d '\000'
```

This turns input into nul separated records i.e. on each line that starts with a `*` (except for the first one) it adds a nul char before the `*` then uses `shuf` with `--zero-terminated` switch to extract five random records and `tr` to delete those nul chars.

Comment: Nice +1. could you please elaborate use of `sed` part ? specifically `\x0*` ?

Comment: If I would be able to upvote again, I surely would have ;) anyways, thanks. It's much clear now.

Comment: @don_crissti, I'm using OS X, I modified it for my OS, but it somehow doesn't work. I wrote the result in my question, could you take a look? It seems sed can't add a null character?

Comment: @don_crissti - Thanks! `gsed` worked with `\x0`! It didn't work with `\x00` btw. Why are there multiple notations for the null character such as `\x0`, `\x00`, and `\x000\`?

Comment: @stacko - `\x00` or `\x0` are hex codes and are equivalent (they both work on my linux setup); `\000` is the octal notation

Comment: @don_crissti - Ah, that makes sense. Thanks, don! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
cat listfile | tr '\n' , | sed 's/,\*/\n*/g;s/,$//' | shuf | head -n 5 | tr , '\n'
```

Comment: there's a corner case for the last line which has an extra comma and leads to a blank link later. Add `;s/,$//`

Comment: @meuh right, I made the edit